Firebase (Phone Auth) Getting iOS error: NativeFirebaseError: [auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token
Issue with Sign-In Using Phone Number on Physical Device and Production in React Native Firebase
Problem
The sign-in with phone number works on the iOS simulator, but it stops working in production or on a physical device. I get the following error when running auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);:

NativeFirebaseError: [auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token.
at signInWithPhoneNumber

Additionally, I'm encountering this error on app load:

NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Setup
I'm using React Native CLI with the following imports and package versions:
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

Package versions:
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.1.0",
"@react-native-firebase/storage": "^20.1.0"

What I've Tried

Updating packages to the latest versions.
Uploading the APNS .p8 key to Firebase.
Ensuring the bundle identifier is correct.
Verifying the correctness of GoogleService-Info.plist.
Updating Firestore rules to:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Request
Any help or advice on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated.

update: Downloaded a new GoogleService-Info.plist and it ended up working ...
